# Supgrouping of Groups Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a following pandas table (schematically):

[image]

Now I would like to sort it...

... in such a way that:

1. The Dataframe is sorted by name
2. The rows which have the same name and similar list elements are grouped together. By "similar" I mean that the two adjacent rows should have a list elements where the difference of the list elements between those rows lies within a certain threshold (here I chose 5).

*In other words:* 
For any two adjacent rows if there exists one element in the first row and one element in the second row such that the difference is within the threshold, then they should be grouped together.

3. those groups should be renamed.

The result should look like:

[image]

**EDIT:**
What I tried:
df.sort_values(['name'],ascending=False).groupby('List')

but of course, this does not work, because each list will be a new group, since I cannot introduce "similarity".

EDIT2: 
Here is a code to reproduce the pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'List' : [[2,4],[3,5],[16,19],[4,1],[14,15],[300,20]],
    'Name' :  ["A","C","A","A","A","A"]})
```

Comment: Have you tried group_by()

Comment: @DoHe Please have a look at my edited question

Comment: Would you care to convert this picture to a reproducible code example?

Comment: Think you should elaborate more on 2. By "similar" I mean that the two adjacent rows should have a list elements where the difference of the list elements between those rows lies within a certain threshold (here I chose 5).

Comment: @coldspeed Not at all, I added it.

Comment: @Tai how do you understand it ? maybe I can explain it to you ?

Comment: Thank you. Next question, are all lists in List of the same shape?

Comment: @coldspeed, Yes they are. Could it also work without being the same shape ?

Comment: @totyped Is that for any two adjacent rows if there exists one element in the first row and one element in the second row such that the difference within the threshold, then they should be grouped together.

Comment: @Tai Yes exactly. You understood it. I will add your description to the question, because it is very nicely written.

Comment: @totyped As long as they are all the same size, it doesn't matter, that simplifies the solution.

Comment: @coldspeed, they are the same size

Comment: Are values in A sorted as well? It seems that the order of A changes after sorting merely on Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need new para 'G' here, and using `groupby`

```
df['G']=df.L.apply(max)
df=df.sort_values(['Name','G'])

df['G']=df.groupby(['Name']).G.apply(lambda x : x.diff().fillna(0).gt(5).cumsum())
df.Name=df.Name+'_'+df.G.astype(str)
df
Out[1287]: 
           L Name  G
0     [2, 4]  A_0  0
3     [4, 1]  A_0  0
4   [14, 15]  A_1  1
2   [16, 19]  A_1  1
5  [300, 20]  A_2  2
1     [3, 5]  C_0  0
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':list('ACAAAA'),'L':[[2,4],[3,5],[16,19],[4,1],[14,15],[300,20]]})
```

This is the update :

```
df['G']=df.L.apply(max)
df['G1']=df.L.apply(min)
df=df.sort_values(['Name','G'])

df['G']=df.groupby(['Name']).G.apply(lambda x : x.diff().fillna(0).gt(5))
df=df.sort_values(['Name','G1'])
df['G1']=df.groupby(['Name']).G1.apply(lambda x : x.diff().fillna(0).gt(5))
df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x : ((x.G)|(x.G1)).cumsum())

df.Name=df.Name+'_'+df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x : ((x.G)|(x.G1)).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).astype(str)
df
Out[1307]: 
           L Name      G     G1
3     [4, 1]  A_0  False  False
0     [2, 4]  A_0  False  False
4   [14, 15]  A_1   True   True
2   [16, 19]  A_1  False  False
5  [300, 20]  A_2   True  False
1     [3, 5]  C_0  False  False
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! So, you take the maximum of each list element... but then I don't quit undertstand how you do it. What is "gt(5)" and "cumsum()" doing ? Would you mind to explain me your code ?

Comment: @totyped first I did diff, to see the different of value , if it is greater than 5 , return the True, which is new start for your subgroup , then we do cumcum, you can test True False True cumsum will return 1,1,2 which is your want, BTW, if it is want you want, you can accept and upvote : -)

Comment: You take the difference with respect to what, if I may ask ?

Comment: @totyped different of max value from each list , to see whether they should belong to the one group, if different is less than 5 it should be one group

Comment: There is a problem! I would like that the difference of both values of the list should be less than 5, not only the max value. So for example: Have a look a your dataframe, with index 0 and 3: The value 2 has a difference of 2 to the value 4 underneath, the value 4 has a difference of value 3 to the "1" underneath. Do you understand ? I would like to group only the ones where **both** values are within the difference threshold, not only the max. How can I do it ??

Comment: Here is works, but this was only a demonstration example.

Comment: @totyped we using the same method twice , min and max is the differnet

Comment: Thanks a lot!! If I apply: df.name=df.name+'_'+df.G.astype(str) at the end to change the names, I get name_False or name_True, but no number? How can I get: name_0,name_1 etc. again ?

Comment: @totyped df.name=df.name+'_'+df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x : ((x.G)|(x.G1)).cumsum()).astype(str)

Comment: I get the following error:  "ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names" Do you know what it means or how to fix it ?

Comment: wanted to try it out, but same problem here.

Comment: @totyped you can change to `df.Name+'_'+df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x : ((x.G)|(x.G1)).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).astype(str)
`

Comment: I still get an error, but mybe I am pasting something incorecctly. Would you mind to ubdate your answer with the complete code, such that I can check ? Thanks! :)

Comment: @DoHe that is the index assign problem , df.Name+'_'+df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x : ((x.G)|(x.G1)).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).asty‌​pe(str), try this

Comment: May I ask you a further question: If I would like to implement that a row is added to the subgroup, if it is difference is less than 5 away from any of the pieces in the subgroup. If the "List" column contains the following list elements, the would all be grouped together: [1,2],[5,6],[9,10],[13,13]. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @totyped this is what i would like to asking too, so do you want [1,2],[5,6] be a group or [5,6],[9,10], since this two combination all under your rule to get the subgroup

Comment: I would like to expand my definition of a subgroup. Let's say that I have two possible supgroups which would both contain the same list [5,6] as you suggested, then they should be merged into one group -> [1,2][5,6][9,10]